# Unpack list into pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given I have a list, how can I unpack it into a pandas data frame such as:

```
data = {u'2344': ["id", "value1", "value2", "01", "Addf112", "Addf113", "02", " ", "Addf213"]}

>> id  value1  value2
   01  Ad112   Ad113
   02          Ad213
```

Comment: Use the first three values for the ```columns``` argument and the rest (taken in groups of three) for the data.  If the list is named ```a``` then ```zip(a[::3], a[1::3], a[2::3]``` should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to extract the individual elements for the column names and then construct a list consisting of 2 lists for your 2 rows of data:

```
In [23]:

data = {u'2344': ["id", "value1", "value2", "01", "Addf112", "Addf113", "02", " ", "Addf213"]}

pd.DataFrame(columns = data['2344'][:3], data=[data['2344'][3:6], data['2344'][6:]])
Out[23]:
   id   value1   value2
0  01  Addf112  Addf113
1  02           Addf213
```

A dynamic method would be to use a chunker (modified from one of the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)) to build the dict and use this to construct the df:

```
In [59]:

def chunker(seq, stride):
    cols = seq[:stride]
    data = [seq[stride:][pos::stride] for pos in range(0, stride)]
    return dict(zip(cols,data))

pd.DataFrame(chunker(data['2344'],3))

Out[59]:
   id   value1   value2
0  01  Addf112  Addf113
1  02           Addf213
```

Comment: is it possible to get the rows dynamically without specifying them manually `data=[data['2344'][3:6], data['2344'][6:]]` ?

Comment: You'd have to know what your data structure was before hand, in this case you'd have to know that the columns were the first three values and the following 3 values are the row data

Comment: I've added some code that should be able to handle a variable length or the rows in the list

Comment: do you happen to have a work around on on the data if it contains subitems in single quotes, `data = {u'2344': ['"id", "value1", "value2"', '"01", "Addf112", "Addf113"',' "02", " ", "Addf213"']}`

Comment: My code would still work, you'd pass the `stride` value as `1` in that case `pd.DataFrame(chunker(data['2344'],1))`

Comment: all the values comes with double quotes, how do I remove this?

Comment: Please post another question, it doesn't help anyone to keep changing your data and question and using comments to seek further answers